# j Query masking for multiple formats (Optional digits)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mask, masking

I am trying to mask CVV card..!

it should allow 3 **or** 4 numbers **xxx** 123  or **xxxx** 4567

I have tried like this but it is allowing only 4 characters, how can I allow both formats with jquery mask plugin

`$("#card_cvv").mask("9999");`       //it is accepting 4 charecters

`$("#card_cvv").mask("999");`           //it is accepting 3 charecters

i want some thing like this combination:    `$("#card_cvv").mask("999 or 9999");`

HTML:

```
<input id="card_cvv" name="ccv" data-toggle="tooltip" required="" value="" class="form-control alt card_cvv" type="text" placeholder="CCV" aria-required="true">
```

Plug in:  https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make sense. How can you restrict the user to entering at most 3 and at most 4 characters simultaneously?

Comment: What do you mean by "allowing only 4 characters"? If you can type 4, you can also type 3.

Comment: @mpen then how can I do the validation for cvv..? After a small research I realized that some credit cards will have `4` numbers and some `3`

Comment: @Herohtar check the plugin once.! when you give 4 number format in the mask and when you enter data in input field it will not take the value when you enter only 3 characters.

Comment: Can you give some more example code of how you are using it? If I enter 3 characters -- for example, 123 -- and then use $("#card_cvv").val() it will give me "123".

Comment: @Herohtar i wrote comments in code pls check once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use `0` for the required digits and `9` for the optional

```js
$("#card_cvv").mask("0009",{ 
  clearIfNotMatch: true 
});

$('button').on('click', function(){
    console.log( $('#card_cvv').cleanVal() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.12/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="card_cvv">

<button>log clear value</button>
```

Comment: I think this is what he was going for, but didn't mention that he was using `clearIfNotMatch`. By the way, I think you mean `0` for required and `9` for optional?

Comment: `0009` with this only last one number is changing.! first 3 are becoming zero's and I can't even able change them

Comment: @AbdulWaheed does the snippet in the answer not work ?

Comment: thanks it is working fine, i used your mask library earlier i have lower version i guess. @GabyakaG.Petrioli

Comment: @AbdulWaheed that would be my next suggestion. Glad to help.